# OpenBSD with LDAP authentication returning invalid user

Tags: ldap, authentication, openbsd

I am trying to set up an OpenBSD box to use a LDAP server for authentication. I am following the directions at http://www.obfuscurity.com/2009/08/OpenBSD-as-an-LDAP-Client and for the most part they seem to be working. When I run `/usr/libexec/auth/login_-ldap -d -s login USERNAME ldap` it authenticates properly, and running `ypldap -dv` shows output lines like "pushing line:" followed by what looks like a passwd file entry for all my ldap users. So far, so good.

However, when I run `getent passwd` it still only shows local users (my understanding was that it should show both local and LDAP users), and when I try to authenticate as any LDAP user, authLog shows "Invalid User". What might I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be very careful that the mappings listed in `/etc/ypldap.conf` are correct for this to work. In this case, the UID parameter was wrong: instead of returning an ID number, it was returning the user name. This does not create an error anywhere, however it does prevent the users from being used.